# how to make slave of slave in sync with it's master

Tags: bind, powerdns

deal all

I I have 3 NS installation.
That is NS0, NS1, NS2.

NS0 (192.168.1.123) is a PowerDns.
Its (sniped) configuration :

```
disable-axfr=no
also-notify=192.168.8.78,192.168.8.79
allow-axfr-ips=127.0.0.0/8,::1,192.168.8.78,192.168.8.79
master=yes
```

NS1 (192.168.8.78) is a BIND9.
and it's configuration :

```
options {
          directory "/var/cache/bind";
          query-source address 192.168.8.78;
          notify-source 192.168.8.78;
          transfer-source 192.168.8.78;
          port 53;
          allow-new-zones yes;
          listen-on { 192.168.8.78; 127.0.0.1; };
          listen-on-v6 { none; };
          notify no;
          recursion no;
          allow-transfer { 192.168.8.79; };
          allow-notify {192.168.1.123;};
          also-notify {192.168.8.79;};
};

logging {
        channel default_file {
                file "/var/log/named/named.log" size 200m;
                severity info;
                print-time yes;
                print-severity yes;
                print-category yes;
        };
        category default{ default_file; };
};

zone "zonecatalog.jc" {
    type master;
    file "zonecatalog.jc.db";
    allow-transfer { 192.168.8.79; };
    allow-update { 127.0.0.1;};
    also-notify { 192.168.8.79; } ;
    notify explicit;
};
```

Yes, it have a catalog zone in it.
I add some zone to this catalog using rndc and nsupdate
i.e :

```
rndc addzone domain0.bino {type slave; file "/var/cache/bind/domain0.bino.cache"; masters { 192.168.1.123 port 53; };};
```

with this, every time there is zone record update at PowerDNS, this NS1 got notified and XFR is done.

My NS2 configuration looks like :

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    dnssec-validation auto;

    listen-on-v6 { none; };

        listen-on { 192.168.8.79; 127.0.0.1; };
    notify no;
        transfer-source 192.168.8.79;
    allow-notify { any;};
    allow-new-zones yes;

        recursion no;
        catalog-zones {
             zone "zonecatalog.jc" default-masters { 192.168.8.78 port 53; };
        };

};

logging {
        channel default_file {
                file "/var/log/named/named.log" size 200m;
                severity info;
                print-time yes;
                print-severity yes;
                print-category yes;
        };
        category default{ default_file; };
};



zone "zonecatalog.jc" {
          type slave;
          file "zonecatalog.jc.db";
          masters { 192.168.8.78 port 53; };
};
```

With this, everytime there is add or del zone happen at NS1, that zone also added/deleted from NS2.

But, when there is a record of a zone updated at NS0, this NS2 is only notified by NS0.
and also ... SOA at NS2 is one step late of NS1.

```
 bino@corobalap  ~/sshfs/fs01/zonesync  dig +short @192.168.8.78 domain0.bino soa
ns1.cpaneldev.mynetwork.net. emailserver.mynetwork.net. 2024032012 3600 1800 1209600 86400
 bino@corobalap  ~/sshfs/fs01/zonesync  dig +short @192.168.8.79 domain0.bino soa
ns1.cpaneldev.mynetwork.net. emailserver.mynetwork.net. 2024032011 3600 1800 1209600 86400
```

So, Kindly please tell me what to check/do so that NS2 always in sync with NS1.